# How to make a phonegap project as library in android?

Tags: android, cordova

I have already created an phonegap android project and it is working fine, now i would like to create same kind of project againg. Might it would be more than 5 apps, so i thought making it as library. 
I have make the project as library and created a new project with different package name. Change the launcher activities name to the libraries launcher activity name. But now the issue  is application error is happening, cannot load the index.html file. 
So i think the way worked on is not the proper one, can anyone please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: show use the error message in your logcat or console here.

Answer (score 2):

you have to assign your initial android project as a library. right click the project, pick properties, then go to android, tick the "is library" box and apply

[image]

For your new projects, you need to "add" the project before as your library as the image above

Comment: I have added like this and then i was able to run the second app also, the splash screen appears. But the i get error for loading index.html file. Application error.

Comment: are you running your app on a device or emulator?

Comment: I have copied www from assets folder of library project to second application, now the application error is not showing.